# Hot to make child element wider than parent

Tags: html, css

I have an `hr` tag inside a `div`
and I can't make the `hr` 100vw for responsive scaling.
It works at 1800px, but it doesn't at other widths.

Look at the code

```css
.container{
max-width:1200px;
height:200px;
background: yellow;
}

.hr-header{
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    color: #EDEDED;
    height: 0.5px;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: -30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <hr class="hr-header">
</div>
```

Comment: Please rewrite your question and be more clear in what you want to achieve. And why do you use margin-left:-30% ? . Anyway, please edit your question so we can understand what you are actually  trying to do

Comment: @Mihai T I have parent <div>-element
Into <div> i have <hr>
But my <div> have max-width:1200
for example, at display width 1500 i have margin-left and margin-right 150
but i cant show my <hr>-element without margins

for full width (100vw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My right code:

```css
.container{
max-width:1200px;
height:200px;
background: yellow;
}

.hr-header{
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    color: #EDEDED;
    height: 0.5px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <hr class="hr-header">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the HR should be 100% for any width then use width:100%,Not sure why you are using width:100vh here.

You can use below code.

```
.hr-header{
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    color: #EDEDED;
    height: 0.5px;
    width: 100%;
    
}
```

Comment: 100% dont work. If i use width:100%, my <hr> tag will be max 1200px (like a parent)